# How to Display search result on another page in react hooks

Tags: react-hooks

I m developing an e-commerce application with react hooks in search component result is shown beneath the component I want to render on search Result component how to redirect search result on the search Result component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { getCategories, list } from "./apiCore";    
import SearchResult from "./SearchResult";




const Search = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    categories: [],
    category: "",
    search: "",
    results: [],
    searched: false,



  });


  const { categories, category, search, results, searched } = data;



  const loadCategories = () => {
    getCategories().then(data => {
      if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
      } else {
        setData({ ...data, categories: data });
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadCategories();
  }, []);

  const searchData = () => {
    // console.log(search, category);
    if (search) {
      list({ search: search || undefined, category: category }).then(
        response => {
          if (response.error) {
            console.log(response.error);
          } else {
            setData({ ...data, results: response, searched: true });
          }
        }
      );
    }
  };



  const searchSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchData();

  };

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setData({ ...data, [name]: event.target.value, searched: false });
  };

  const searchMessage = (searched, results) => {
    if (searched && results.length > 0) {
      return `Found ${results.length} products`;
    }
    if (searched && results.length < 1) {
      return `No products found`;
    }
  };

  const searchedProducts = (results = []) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="text-muted mb-4">
          {searchMessage(searched, results)}
        </h2>
        <div className="row">
          {results.map((product, i) => (
            <CarouselCard key={i} product={product} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };



  return (
    <div className="site-navbar-top">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row align-items-center">
          <div className="col-6 col-md-4 order-2 order-md-1 site-search-icon text-left">
            <form className="site-block-top-search" onSubmit={searchSubmit}>
              <span className="icon icon-search2"></span>
              <input type="text" className="form-control border-0" placeholder="Search" onChange={handleChange("search")} />
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="col-12 mb-3 mb-md-0 col-md-4 order-1 order-md-2 text-center">
            <div className="site-logo">
              <Link to="/" className="js-logo-clone">Shoppers</Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-6 col-md-4 order-3 order-md-3 text-right">
            <div className="site-top-icons">
              <ul>
                <li><Link to="#"><span className="icon icon-person" /></Link></li>
                <li><Link to="#"><span className="icon icon-heart-o" /></Link></li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="cart.html" className="site-cart">
                    <span className="icon icon-shopping_cart" />
                    <span className="count">2</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {searchedProducts(results)}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Search;
```

The main part of the hook is pretty straightforward, but I'm having a difficult time finding a nice way to handle that redirect. The current working solution is to wrap the functional component with withRouter, then pass props.history